# Inconsistent "undefined reference to..." errors when building SDL with MinGW/Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, c, mingw, sdl, codeblocks

I have 3 independent files, two are .c files, one is .cpp.

When I try to build/run in Code::Blocks one of the .c files I get an "undefined reference to `SDL_main'" build error.

first file (let's call it SDLtest1.c) builds and runs:

```
//-----< includes >-----//
// Using SDL and standard IO
#include "SDL.h"
#include <stdio.h>

//-----< globals and constants >-----//
//screen dimension constants
typedef enum {
    SCREEN_WIDTH = 640,
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480,
}SCREEN_DIMENSIONS;

//-----< main >-----//
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // The window we'll be rendering to
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    // The surface contained by the window
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

    // Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 ) {
        printf( "SDL could not be initialized! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    }
    else {
        // Create Window
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial",
                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                SCREEN_WIDTH,
                SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if( window == NULL ){
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        } else {
        // Get window surface
        screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( window );

        // Fill the surface white
        SDL_FillRect( screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF) );

        // Update the surface
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );

        // Wait two seconds
        SDL_Delay( 2000 );
        }
    }

    // Destroy Window
    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );

    // Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

I also have a .cpp file (lets call it SDLexample.cpp) that builds and runs:

```
//Using SDL and standard IO
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

//Starts up SDL and creates window
bool init();

//Loads media
bool loadMedia();

//Frees media and shuts down SDL
void close();

//The window we'll be rendering to
SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;

//The surface contained by the window
SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface = NULL;

//The image we will load and show on the screen
SDL_Surface* gHelloWorld = NULL;

bool init()
{
    //Initialization flag
    bool success = true;

    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Create window
        gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if( gWindow == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
            success = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Get window surface
            gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( gWindow );
        }
    }

    return success;
}

bool loadMedia()
{
    //Loading success flag
    bool success = true;

    //Load splash image
    gHelloWorld = SDL_LoadBMP( "02_getting_an_image_on_the_screen/hello_world.bmp" );
    if( gHelloWorld == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Unable to load image %s! SDL Error: %s\n", "02_getting_an_image_on_the_screen/hello_world.bmp", SDL_GetError() );
        success = false;
    }

    return success;
}

void close()
{
    //Deallocate surface
    SDL_FreeSurface( gHelloWorld );
    gHelloWorld = NULL;

    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow( gWindow );
    gWindow = NULL;

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //Start up SDL and create window
    if( !init() )
    {
        printf( "Failed to initialize!\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        //Load media
        if( !loadMedia() )
        {
            printf( "Failed to load media!\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            //Apply the image
            SDL_BlitSurface( gHelloWorld, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL );

            //Update the surface
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( gWindow );

            //Wait two seconds
            SDL_Delay( 2000 );
        }
    }

    //Free resources and close SDL
    close();

    return 0;
}
```

But this third file (SDLtest2.c) fails to build as follows:

```
C:\MinGW\lib\libSDL2main.a(SDL_windows_main.o):SDL_windows_main.c|| undefined reference to `SDL_main'|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

third file:

```
//-----< includes >-----//
#include "SDL.h"
#include <stdio.h>

//-----< preprocessor directives >-----//
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
typedef int BOOLEAN;

//-----< globals and constants >-----//
typedef enum {
    SCREEN_WIDTH = 640,
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480
}SCREEN_DIMENSION;

// The window we'll be rendering to
SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;

// The surface contained by the window
SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface = NULL;

// The image we will load and show on the screen
SDL_Surface* gHelloWorld = NULL;

//-----< forward declarations >-----//
// Starts up SDL and creates window
BOOLEAN init();

// Loads media
BOOLEAN loadMedia();

// Frees media and shuts down SDL
void close();

//-----< main >-----//
int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    // Start up SDL and create window
    if( !init() ) {
        printf( "Failed to initialize!\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        // Load media
        if( !loadMedia() ) {
            printf( "Failed to load media!\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            // Apply the image
            SDL_BlitSurface( gHelloWorld, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL );

            // Update the surface
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( gWindow );

            // Wait two seconds
            SDL_Delay( 2000 );
        }
    }

    // Free resources and close SDL
    close();

    return 0;
}


//-----< function definitions >-----//

BOOLEAN init() {
    // Initialization flag
    BOOLEAN success = TRUE;

    // Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 ) {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        success = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        // Create a window
        gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial",
                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                SCREEN_WIDTH,
                SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if( gWindow == NULL ) {
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetEror() );
            success = FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            //Get window surface
            gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( gWindow );
        }

    return success;
}

BOOLEAN loadMedia() {
    // Loading success flag
    BOOLEAN success = TRUE;

    // Load splash image
    gHelloWorld = SDL_LoadBMP( "02_getting_an_image_on_the_screen/hello_world.bmp" );
    if( gHelloWorld == NULL ) {
        printf( "Unable to load image %s! SDL Error: %s\n", "02_getting_an_image_on_the_screen/hello_world.bmp", SDL_GetError() );
        success = FALSE;
    }

    return success;
}

void close() {
    // Deallocate surface
    SDL_FreeSurface( gHelloWorld );
    gHelloWorld = NULL;

    // Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow( gWindow );
    gWindow = NULL;

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

I've looked over and over the third file for typos that could cause the build error and haven't found any (although I surely could have missed one). I have looked over similar forum questions but nothing has been an exact match and the fact that the other two files build and run successfully suggests to me that the problem isn't with my Code::Blocks or SDL set-up.

I know this is all a lot to look over and appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Comment: What operating system you're running

Comment: @rullof: "C:\MinGW" "SDL_windows_main" Whaddya reckon?

Comment: @user2914028: Remove functions and objects one by one until you have a _minimal testcase_ reproducing the issue. Also include compiler invocation commands.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Thank you for the suggestion. Following your advice revealed two typographical errors which, once fixed, got everything running again. For posterity the first was misspelling Error as Eror in one place, the other was a mismatched curly brace in the function definitions.

Comment: @user2914028: I hope we've learned something here today! :)